# How to make this banner ad same as in another site

Tags: css

How to make red banner ad shown in the top of : http://forum.creditcardpaymentgateways.in/index.php same as shown in this site: http://www.creditcardpaymentgateways.in ?

I've tried to use this code but not working out:

```
<div id="anu-utility2" WIDTH="525" style="margin:auto auto">
<a href="http://www.creditcardpaymentgateways.in/pc-tech-support-payment-gateway-new-offer-from-mumbai-based-comapny.html"><img style="display:block;width:529px;margin:auto auto" WIDTH="529" HEIGHT="75" src="http://www.creditcardpaymentgateways.in/images/banners/celebrationoffer4.jpg" title="Click here" /></a></div>
```

I want to remove the light colored background rectangle behind the red banner(used in the forum):
[image]

The forum is in PHPBB and Site is in Joomla.

Comment: I want to remove the light colored rectangle behind the red banner. I want to use the background color as in the pane below which contains Search/Text Size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should move anu-utility2 to  into rt-utility3

Your Example Source Code:

```
<div id="rt-utility" class="feature-shadows-light">
    <div id="rt-utility2">
        <div id="rt-utility3">
            **<div id="anu-utility2" width="525" style="margin: auto auto">
                <a href="http://www.creditcardpaymentgateways.in/pc-tech-support-payment-gateway-new-offer-from-mumbai-based-comapny.html">
                    <img style="display: block; width: 529px; margin: auto auto" width="529" height="75"
                        src="http://www.creditcardpaymentgateways.in/images/banners/celebrationoffer4.jpg"
                        title="Click here"></a></div>**
            <div class="rt-grid-6 rt-alpha">

            </div>
            <div class="rt-grid-2 rt-omega">

            </div>
            <div class="clear">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want same as the below image.

[image]

You need the gradient image and the below code to achieve this

css:

img
{
    border:none;
}

#bannerbg
{
    background:url(gradient-div.png) repeat-x;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    height:75px;
}

HTML:

```
<div id="bannerbg">

<div id="anu-utility2" WIDTH="525" style="margin:auto auto">
<a href="http://www.creditcardpaymentgateways.in/pc-tech-support-payment-gateway-new-offer-from-mumbai-based-comapny.html"><img style="display:block;width:529px;margin:auto auto" WIDTH="529" HEIGHT="75" src="http://www.creditcardpaymentgateways.in/images/banners/celebrationoffer4.jpg" title="Click here" /></a></div>

</div>
```